# Not getting the required output

Tags: c++, syntax

```
#include  <iostream>

using namespace std;

int *GetSquare(int x)
{
    int y = x;

    y = y * y;
    return &y;
}

int main()
{
    const int n = 4;
    int *p[n];

    for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
    {
        p[2 * j + 1] = new int[2];

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
            p[2 * j + 1][i] = 2 * j + 1;
    }
    p[0] = GetSquare(2);
    p[2] = GetSquare(4);

    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; ++i)
            cout << p[j][i] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I dry run this code I get the output "4 1 16 3".
while in the compiler i get "16 1 3 3"
theres no way the in which i can find the first output to be 16. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: One thing I notice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope

Comment: Please change your title to something more relevant to the problem you're having. "Not getting the right output" pretty much applies to any software bug ever.

Comment: One issue is that your `GetSquare` is returning a pointer to a variable which is local to `GetSquare`. That's bad. Why don't you just return the value? And what do you mean, *When I dry run this code...*? What's it actually supposed to do?

Comment: He probably means debug, but I'm not editting it in in case he means something else. @lurker

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
int *GetSquare(int x)
{
    int y = x;
    y = y * y;
    return &y;
}
```

is a *very bad thing*.

You are returning the address of a value on the stack, which is invalidated once leaving the function. **You cannot rely on what lives at that address once you've left the function.**

You write:

```
p[0] = GetSquare(2);
```

and you might think `p[0]` is a pointer to an integer with the value 4. Except that pointer was only valid within `GetSquare`.

The problem seems engineered to be bad. Why not return an actual integer value from GetSquare, rather than a pointer to an invalid memory address?

```
int GetSquare(int x) { return x * x; }
```

EDIT:
The question could be simplified to this:

```
int* GetSquare(int x)
{
    int y = x;
    y = y * y;
    return &y;
}

int main()
{
    int* p = GetSquare(2);
    int* q = GetSquare(4);
    cout << "p == q? " << (p == q ? "YES" : "NO") << endl;
    cout << p << " " << q << " " << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Run that in debug mode, run in release, with various levels of debug info and/or optimization... You *might* sometimes get `4 16`, but probably not. It may also sometimes say `p` and `q` are the same, sometimes not.

The link in chris's comment has a decent explanation.

Comment: Some of the code in `main` will subsequently need to be refactored as well since the OP was counting on `GetSquare` returning a pointer to the value.

Comment: @lurker Very true... left as an exercise for the reader.  ;)  But seriously, the original question is rather... bizarre... almost like it was written to specifically do bad things at bad times to bad people. At a glance, I'm not convinced that `GetSquare` is the *only* bad pointery thing in there. `GetSquare` is an obvious problem, but perhaps not the only.

Comment: All true. :) I was just thinking if one is indicating a solution, pointing out the obvious knock-on effects is helpful but I agree: exercise for the reader. Lots of goblins in the question and code.

Comment: The rest of the code is *safe* but *ugly*.

Answer (score 0):

Your ptogram has undefined behaviour because you are returning pointer to a local object of the function that will be destroyed after exiting it.

```
int *GetSquare(int x)
{
    int y = x;

    y = y * y;
    return &y;
}
```

Also it does not make sense to return pointer instead of a temporary object. The function could be written like

```
long long int GetSquare( int x )
{
    return ( long long int )x * x;
}
```